# Check if subprocess called with shell=True is still running

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a process which for certain reasons, I **must** call with the following (please don't judge...)

```
process = subprocess.Popen("some_command &", shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')
```

`some_command` is supposed to terminate by itself when some external conditions are met.

How can I check when `some_command` has terminated?

```
process.poll()
```

always returns `0`

A simple script to demonstrate my situation:

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen("sleep 5 &", shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')

while True:
    print(process.poll())
```

Comment: Are you certain it is still running?

Comment: The `&` will prevent effective control over the process. You should remove it.

Comment: @StephenRauch yes, edited question to add demonstration

Comment: `process.poll() == None` means the process is alive.

Comment: Without judging: Using `&` in `bash` just means "run in background". The default behavior for `subprocess.Popen` is to run the process in the background, so `subprocess.Popen(['some_command'])` should behave the same, except with fewer layers of processes, and without losing the connection between Python and `some_command` (the connection having been lost because `bash` exits and orphans `some_command`; you're seeing `bash`'s exit code).

Comment: @l'L'l: `process.poll() is None` would be the canonical approach (always use `is`/`is not` when comparing to language guaranteed singletons like `None`). Irrelevant here though, since the `bash` process is exiting almost immediately (since all it does is launch the child in the background, then exit).

Comment: @ShadowRanger your comment about `&` solved my problem, if you put it as an answer, i'll accept it (additionally, is there any other side effect for using `&`?)

Comment: @ShadowRanger: Yep, definitely agree; wasn't sure the OP was aware though, so figured I'd mention it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`some_command &` tells `bash` to run `some_command` in the background. This means that your shell launches `some_command`, then promptly exits, severing the tie between the running `some_command` and your Python process (`some_command`'s parent process no longer exists after all). `poll()` is accurately reporting that `bash` itself finished running, exiting with status 0; it has no idea what may or may not be happening with `some_command`; that's `bash`'s problem (and `bash` didn't care either).

If you want to be able to poll to check if `some_command` is still running, don't background it via `bash` shell metacharacters; without `&`, `bash` will continue running until it finishes, so you'll have an indirect indication of when `some_command` finishes from the fact that `bash` itself is still running. It's still in the background (in the sense that it runs in parallel with your Python code; the Python process won't stall waiting on it or anything unless you explicitly `wait` or `communicate` with `process`):

```
process = subprocess.Popen("some_command", shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')
```

Of course, unless `some_command` is some `bash` builtin, `bash` is just getting in the way here; as noted `subprocess.Popen` *always* runs stuff in the background unless you explicitly ask for it to `wait`, so you didn't need `bash`'s help to background anything:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(["some_command"])
```

would get similar behavior, and actually let you examine the return code from `some_command` directly, with no intermediary `bash` process involved.